# PHP server connection test

Tags: php

Is there a php script/snippets out there that allows you to check a URL/IP for connection speed. Say example the URL is www.example.com and when I run the php script it will display how long it took to connect (211ms) to the URL/IP, I found some scripts that just show me if it's online or offline but not the speed it took.

I'm very aware of the free and paid services. I want create my own custom/private one to monitor my many servers and having trouble finding a simple script to connect to given locations.

Comment: connection speed and ping are different things.

Comment: @zerkms yes that's why I'm asking if anyone is aware of a example script to get connection speed and or if it's possible to do with php. :)

Comment: @DanielO It is not possible to do this in PHP alone because you need something client side as well. Also it's not as simple as "this is the speed of connection X", there are so many factors that can affect it. For example you could use a TCP stream to determine it, but there is a higher overhead cost with all those ACKs. Or you could use a UDP stream, but then what do you do if you lose packets? Do you consider that to be adversely affecting the speed or do you just care about the total data payload transmitted in time frame X? It's not clear cut, and it's not trivial to implement.

Comment: @DaveRandom I see what you mean. I just want to log and compare so if I notice one of the server getting slow I can do something about it. So if there is any other method to get est idea of speed would work.

Comment: @DanielO OK, now we're getting somewhere. What do the servers *do*? Are they web servers?

Comment: @DaveRandom the are web servers that are behind a LB and server http port 80 webpages

Comment: OK well I suspect that server load would be a more sensible thing to monitor, for which there are many tools available. Polling the server from a remote location will give an unrealistic impression of usage and won't really tell you anything. If the servers are heavily loaded enough for this to be an issue, I *highly* recommend spending some money here - it doesn't have to be a lot, but a tried and tested commercial product will give you a *much* better view of this, and might actually give you some useful information.

Comment: @DaveRandom I have services on each of my servers that alert me of cpu/load issues or if they quit responding. The problem is the load balancer is hosted/custom by a third party to support 130,000 concurrent connections and when I get to about 90,000 connections the LB loads the webpage slow. I know there are third party services but I want to create my own so it can trigger a few things remotely to do stuff. The Curl has worked for me as I did a remote test with the sleep command for 10 seconds and it reported it as 10 seconds. Just the LB reports fine for my monitoring but shows blank page.

Comment: I got what I needed maybe a better wording would of work and or the TCP would be nice to.

Comment: @DanielO At the very least you should throw a few hundred concurrent connections at it in order to get a realistic representation of load times when your talking on the scale of tens of thousands of concurrent connections. Basing it off one connection is like saying "I can't see any sharks from my bedroom window, therefore there are no sharks in the ocean". `exec()`ing [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) would be a decent poor-mans approach to this.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm not trying to benchmark*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
<?php
// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occured
if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
}
// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: It's loading yahoo directly in the page?

Comment: Sorry, I put false instead of true, i have edited and tested.

Comment: -1 because this does not answer the question - a HTML over HTTP page load time from a heavily loaded server has pretty much nothing to do with connection speed

Comment: Works thank you! Just needed something that gave me a ruff idea.

Comment: @DaveRandom He was only looking for an idea of how to do it, he wanted to test the speed of the site not just the connect speed. The -1 is un-justified.

He accepted my answer then unaccepted it :(

Comment: @KyleHudson: The -1 wasnt just for your answer, I think DaveRandom gave a -1 to the accepted answer as well! I am +1 ing your answer because for me, what you answered makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$start = microtime();
$foo = curl_exec($ch);
$end = microtime();
curl_close($ch);

echo "Seconds to load = ". $end - $start;
```

This won't consider images or javascript, just the intital response time and running of server code.

Comment: That's all I need is response not page load speed. I tested it and get `-0.694715` is that correct 694ms?

Comment: -1 because this does not answer the question (a HTML over HTTP page load time from a heavily loaded server has pretty much nothing to do with connection speed) and also because you code doesn't work, mostly because you didn't pass `true` to `microtime()`.

Comment: @DaveRandom: This answer does what is intended. Actually your comment should get a -1 because you did not understand what the OP was asking for where as the person who answered did. I am +1 ing the answer